# D3 sankey chart nodes click event not working in google chrome (58.0.3029.110) version

Tags: d3.js, charts, click, nodes

D3 sankey chart nodes click event not working in updated google chrome (58.0.3029.110) version. Before update it was working fine. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Remove

> this.parentNode.appendChild(this)

from the dragstart event listener. It works. Not sure what's the purpose of this line.

Update 1:
The purpose of the line is to bring the element (that is getting dragged currently) to the top of the other elements inside the same parent.

Comment: I was facing the same issue with D3's Sankey chart. Here is the link: http://bl.ocks.org/Neilos/584b9a5d44d5fe00f779